# Open VS 2019 Community Edition

Tags: visual-studio

I have installed VS 2019 professional Edition. Due to the license issue, I installed VS 2019 community edition. But when I open VS 2019 from the windows start button, profession Edition is opening. How I can open community edition by default.?

Note: I don't want to uninstall the professional Edition, as I can use it once my license issue is resolved.

Comment: ... uninstall professional?

Comment: You clicked on the wrong icon. You now have *two* icons, one for each version. There's no problem with running two editions side by side. When you double-click on a `sln` or `csproj` file you'll even see a version selector asking you which VS edition to use